# System.Web.HttpException: Section not defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following _Layout.cshtml:

```
@using System.Web.Optimization
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Structured Content </title>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
</head>
<body>
    <div id="layout">
    <div id="header">
        <div class="menu_header">
            <h2 style="float: left;">Logo</h2>
            @RenderSection("menu_header");
        </div>
    </div>
        <div id="bottom_menu">
        </div>
    <div id="media">
        @RenderSection("media");
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="maincontent">
            @RenderBody();
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        Foooter
    </div>
    </div>


    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

In my index.cshtml, I have the following:

```
@{
    Layout = "../Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section menu_header {

<div class="login_menu_links">

    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="top_ranked_menu">Top ranked&#9660;</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="sign_in_style">
 <form>
    <span style="display:inline-block">
        <label>Email</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="email">

    </span>
    <span style="display:inline-block">
        <label>Password</label><br/>
        <input type="password" name="pass">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in">
    </span>
</form>
</div>

}


@section media {
    <img src="https://marshallamps.com/wp-content/themes/marshallamps/images/brand-video-overlay.jpg" width="755">
<img src="https://www.marshallheadphones.com/media/upload/pressimages/marshall/MIXEDMEDIA/EVENT/instac.jpg">
<img src="http://blog.weddingfavorsbynette.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/wedding-music-dj-624x416.jpg" width="498">

}

<div id="leftcontent">
     <h2 class="news_title">Get discovered as a band or musician<br />here on Namn. </h2>
     <ul class="info_text">
         <li><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/vote/16/medal_star_rank-512.png" width="30" height="30">Gather karma points - get ranked</li>
         <li><img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/770/token_dark/128/headphones.png" width="32" height="32">Explore new music - all genres</li>
         <li><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gray-user-toolbar/512/social_network-512.png" width="30" height="30">Connect - with musicians and friends</li>
     </ul>
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#top_ranked_menu').mouseover(function () {
        $('#bottom_menu').show();
    });

    $('#bottom_menu').mouseout(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
</script>
```

When I run my application, I get the following error message:

Section not defined: "menu_header".

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
>   Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Section not defined:
>   "menu_header".

As I can see, I have defined them?

Comment: I'm assuming you've tried re-building your solution, or re-running and not just refreshing in your browser?

Comment: @kevindeleon: Ofc I have.

Comment: Can you post your controller code where you are loading this view? I can't imagine anything being wrong, but you never know.

Comment: Even tho this has no answer, this still helped me, since I realized that I could define the section to not be required (required: false), which basically caused my error.